# What effect does this line have in a shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, temp

I've seen this line in many shell scripts but I don't understand the effect it has. Could someone explain please?

```
tempfile=`tempfile 2>/dev/null` || tempfile=/tmp/test$$
```

Comment: All of it. I'm not exactly sure what tempfile does and I don't understand the re-direction to /dev/null

Comment: @Sheldon As an aside, `man tempfile` says "tempfile is deprecated; you should use `mktemp`(1) instead."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It creates a temporary file and puts the path to it in the $tempfile variable.

```
`tempfile 2>/dev/null`
```

runs the tempfile command (`man tempfile`) and discards any error messages. If it succeeds, it returns the name of the newly created temporary file. If it fails, it returns non-zero, in which case the next part of the command runs.

For a command `this || that`, `that` only runs if `this` fails, i.e. returns non-zero.

`$$` is a variable in bash that expands to the process ID of the shell. (Compare the results of `ps` and `echo $$`.) So `tempfile=/tmp/test$$` will expand to something like `tempfile=/tmp/test2278`.

Presumably, later in the script, something writes to $tempfile.

Answer (score 3):

The shell has a separate namespace for command and variables (making it a Lisp-2, LOL) which is exploited in your script line. `tempfile` is a command which is run to compute the value of the `tempfile` variable which is unrelated to it in any way. `tempfile` produces a pathname suitable for use as the name of a temporary file. `2> /dev/null` redirects any error message from `tempfile` into `/dev/null` (2 is the standard error file descriptor). The `command1 || command2` logic means, "execute command2 if command1 fails". If we can't get a temporary name from `tempfile`, then we use `/tmp/test$$`, where `$$` is a special built-in shell parameter which expands to the shell's own process ID.

Answer (score 2):

tempfile creates a temporay file with a file name similar to /tmp/tmp.XXXXXX

2>/dev/null redirects the command output to the /dev/null device, which just throws it away. This redirection just ignore any errors on creating a temporary file.

|| chains two commands together. If the first fails, the second is executed. If the first succeeds nothing else happens.

$$ is the pid of the current shell, which means that if the tempfile command fails the tempfile variable will still contain a string in the form /tmp/test6052 if the process' pid is 6052.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the line, up to the `||`, runs the program `tempfile` and captures standard output in the variable `tempfile`, throwing errors away.  There's an exit status, too: either zero for success or non-zero for failure (either failure to execute the `tempfile` command or failure reported by the `tempfile` command when it is run).

The `||` means "if the LHS (left-hand side) failed then do the RHS (right-hand side)".

So, if the `tempfile` command had a problem, the RHS will be used, assigning a simpler temporary file name to `tempfile` (the variable).

Overall, it is equivalent to:

```
if tempfile=`tempfile 2>/dev/null`
then : OK
else tempfile=/tmp/test$$
fi
```

Only it is on one line, not four.

The idea is, I'm sure, to get something in `$tempfile` whether or not the `tempfile` command exists on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at [man tempfile](http://www.cs.vassar.edu/cgi-bin/man/man2html?1%20tempfile)?

That line is trying to use `tempfile(1)` to generate a temporary filename, storing it in `$tempfile`.  If that fails (the "||", "or" part), it falls back to an explicit filename of `/tmp/test$$`, where `$$` is [the PID of the executing script](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#PROCCID).